# How to change the title text position on the toolbar?

Tags: android

I recently got into android development. I just started on my first app and was wondering how to move the app title right next to the drawer icon instead of it being in the middle like this.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqsbf.png)

Is there anyway to do this at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally,the app title is right next to the drawer icon. I think your layout file may have a problem, can you show you layout code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MpBTdwVw Here is the code. I change to size of the toolbar in order to to get it to look like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/L5lSA.png but with the title at the top. I am guessing the title changes so it is positioned in the middle and since it is extended. Do you know if there is any way to bypass this?

Comment: Try to use a extra TextView in your Toolbar with the attribute "android:layout_gravity="top" .

Comment: Just like this : `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`